# Why am I getting "array initializer must be an initializer list or string literal"?

Tags: c, arrays

I am completely new to C programming and the language I used to work on before C was Java. I am trying to get a method to return a char array and it is not working. Here is my syntax:

```
char * insertToArray(char * val){
    int k;
    char arr[2] = val;
    // do some other staffs here to the value
    return arr;
}

int main(){
    char s1[] = {"one", "two"};
    char newArr[];
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        newArr[] = insertToArray(s1[i]);
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

All I am trying to do is pass the `s1` array to `insertToArray` and do some kind of calculation on the values, then return a whole new single array. I am a complete beginner and I couldn't find any other help online. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you expecting to happen with this line: `char arr[2] = val;`?

Comment: `char s1[]` --> `char *s1[]`

Comment: You are getting it because in C language "array initializer must be an initializer list or string literal", just like the compiler told you. Your `char arr[2] = val;` violates that rule.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rules of C says that you can't initialize an array using a pointer. Instead define the array then copy to it:

```
char arr[strlen(val) + 1];  // Make sure there's enough space
strcpy(arr, val);
```

Then you can not define empty arrays. An array must have a size. And using the array `newArr` in the `main` function is wrong anyway since the function you call returns a *pointer*. So `newArr` must be a pointer as well.

---

Now with that out of the way, there are a couple of other things in your (current) code that are very wrong.

The first being the size of the array `arr`. An array of two characters can only hold space for one-character string. Remember that strings are null terminated, there must be space for the full string *plus* the terminator.

The second problem is that you return a pointer to a local variable. Once the function `insertToArray` returns, all its local variables cease to exist. Having a pointer to one of those variables will lead to *undefined behavior* when you use it.

The fix to the first problem is shown above. The fix to the second problem is a little harder, and involves either passing an extra argument to the function or allocating memory dynamically. I recommend the extra argument way:

```
char * insertToArray(const char * val, char * arr){
    strcpy(val, arr);

    // do some other staffs here to the value

    return arr;
}
```

Then call it like

```
char newArr[strlen(s1[i]) + 1];
insertToArray(s1[i], newArr);
```